# Using jQuery .change() to change values in a <p> element

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select element with a few options for currencies, and then a `<p>` element at the bottom that currently prints the current exchange rate for USD to another currency. What I'm trying to do, is upon `.change()` of the select element value, I want to insert the value of the select element into a PHP script, and then re-`.load()` the `<p>` element.

How can I pass a value from jQuery .val() to a PHP script?

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload then you have to use AJAX. Jquery has built in functions check it out! http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want something like:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('p').load('/path/to/script.php?myVar=' + $(this).val());
});
```

Of course, you might want to use more specific selectors.

Comment: Well, I was halfway through writing a similar answer when Doug beat me to it. This is probably the simplest solution since it sounds like you're already using load() in your script.

Comment: Have had problems in the past with val() not working consistently in all browsers, so I always use .attr('value') now.

Comment: @mick In the case of a `<select>` element, though, what one would usually want is the value of the selected `<option>`. `$('select').attr('value')` returns the value attribute of the `<select>` element, whereas `$('select').val()` is sneakier.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax. Here's an example of how to do this with JQuery:

```
$('#selectElement').change(function(){
   var currentSelection = $('#selectElement').attr('value');
   $.get('yourScript.php?selection=' + currentSelection, function(data){
      $('#pElement').html(data);
   })
});
```

Or something like that.  Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('#mySelect').change(function(){
      jQuery.ajax({
             url:'myPhpFile.php'
             type:'get'
             data:{currencyId:jQuery(this).val()},
             success:function(data)
             {
               jQuery('#myDiv').html(data);
             }
      });      
});
```